# Append location.hash from current URL to target URL

Tags: javascript, html, button, window.location

I have a url with a hash value at the end: test123.com/go#whathaveyou

How would I go about appending the hash value to the target url in a button onclick url target:

```
<form target="_blank" id="form1">
<input onclick="window.location.href='test123.com/newpage'+location.hash;" type="Submit" value="GO" style="border-radius: 5px;"/></form>
```

End goal is to go to the new page with the hash value appended so: test123.com/newpage#whathaveyou

Comment: If the purpose of the interaction is to go to a new page, why are you using an `<input>` and not, for example, an `<a>` element? Or should the `<form>` be submitted to that listed URL?

Comment: An <a>element would work as well. But I would prefer the button if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you give that input the id "link":

```
var elem = document.getElementById('link');
var url = window.location.href;
var res = url.split("#");
var hash = res[1];
elem.addEventListener('click, function () {
    window.location = https://test123.com/newpage'+ hash;
});
```

You can condense this code a lot, just wanted it to be as readable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also:

```html
<input onclick="window.location=(window.location.href).split('#')[1]" type="Submit" value="GO" style="border-radius: 5px;"/></form>
```

Short and clear